# Symmetric closure

Tags: education

Let  be a relation on a non-empty set . Define, **explicitly in terms of** , the relation which is the symmetric closure of .

i just started on relations and is confused by how do i go about proving this question in terms of R.

Comment: To me, "the smallest symmetric relation (or equivalently, the intersection of all symmetric relations) on  containing  as a subset" is the definition of the symmetric closure. I suspect that that's not what they are after, though.

Answer (score 2):

If $R \subset A \times A$ is a relation on $A$ then we have that the symmetric closure of $R$ is
$$\bar{R} = R \cup \{(y, x): (x, y) \in R\}.$$
So you just add the mirror images of all the relators (if they are not already elements of the relation). To prove that this is indeed the symmetric closure, first make the easy observation that the relation is symmetric now. Moreoever, any other symmetric relation containing $R$ also contains the mirror images of $R$ (by symmetry). Since we have added nothing else, we get the other inclusion.